# External database connection via TYPO3 within a userfunction

Tags: database-connection, external, typo3-6.2.x

I am using TYPO3 6.2.X and have a second extern database and I need to update a value from a table of this database.

So I have implemented a simple userfunction like the following example (pseudocode):

```
public function updateValue() {

    $updateData = array(
        'field1' => '1',
        'field2' => '2'
    );

    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_UPDATEquery(
        'example',
        'value = 1234',
        $updateData
    );

}
```

That's not the problem so far, but the table "example" is a table of a extern database. For this reason I have activated dbal and adodb via extension manager. After that I have created the file **typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php** which contains the following configuration:

```
<?php
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['dbal']['handlerCfg'] = array (
'_DEFAULT' => array (
    'type' => 'native',
    'config' => array(
        'username' => '',
        'password' => '',
        'host' => '',
        'database' => '',
    )
),
'extdatabase' => array (
    'type' => 'native',
        'config' => array(       
        'username' => 'username',        
        'password' => 'password',        
        'host' => 'host',        
        'database' => 'extern_database',        
    )
),
);
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['dbal']['table2handlerKeys'] = array(
    'example' => 'extdatabase',
);
?>
```

but this is not working and I got the following exception:

**ERROR: No handler for key "extdatabase"** :(

So the extension configuration of dbal is not set correctly. The [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/dbal/)  of dbal  seems to be out of date because there is no reference to AdditonalConfiguration.php but localconf.php. So I dont know how I can solve this problem, hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn :/

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['dbal']['handlerCfg']
```

have to be

```
$GLOBALS['EXTCONF']['dbal']['handlerCfg']
```

and then it is working correctly.